# How To Move A DIV Element A Little Towards The Top

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have an issue with the home-link image that I've coded for my hovering navigation bar. The URL to my blog is as follows : http://www.blankesque.com. I would ideally like the image to appear in-line with the tabs text that is beside it however no matter what I do I cant seem to move the "home" icon slightly up. I have tried to play about with padding and margin values but to no avail. I only need to move the image approximately 15px towards the top but I cant figure out how to go about it. I have included the html and css coding below :

```
#wctopdropcont { 
width:100%;
height:45px;
display:block;
padding: 5.5px 0 0 0;
z-index:100;
top:-2px;
left: 0px;
position:fixed;

background:#f8f8f8;
opacity: 0.9;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
 }
</style>

<div id='wctopdropcont'>

<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'><img alt='Home' height='30px' src='http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah140/mynamesiram/Mobile%20Uploads/520FDB25-EAD9-4BB0-B621-B1BFE3B558A9_zpsua6eoor2.gif' width='30px'/></a></li> 
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use any margins and stuff.

The problem is you have padding on your img.

set padding: 0; only to on the first li and it will be fine..

[image]

```
#wctopdropnav li:first-child { padding: 0; }
```

Comment: #wctopdropnav li:first-child {
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however this line of code then affects the first-child of all my li which includes my dropdown menu options

Comment: Yeah that's just the idea if you have only this one.
You can give it an id.. I think you can handle it :)

Answer (score 1):

That happens because of the native ul and li margin/padding. You can use negative top margin specifically for the img.

```
#wctopdropnav ul li a img {margin-top:-13px;}
```

If you are going to have more imgs in the top nav, you can add a class/id to the home-icon image and add the CSS specifically to that class.

Comment: No that's wrong, he has the `ul` margin and padding set to 0

Comment: The UL margin/padding is set to 0, but li's not. it has 10pixels margin top.

Comment: that is `margin-left:10px` not margin top

Comment: That's padding-top. Use Chromes Inspector > computed styles tab

Comment: using computed tab, padding-top10px is for `li` not for `ul`, for `ul` it is 0

Answer (score 0):

A **quick hack** could be this:

add to your home-icon the following property:

```
margin: -10px;
```

However, to keep your css **more maintainable**, I would recommend finding the reason why the image is not aligned properly. To do this, you could use browser tools like the Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

When you inspect your home button, you'll see that

- a padding of 5 px is added because you define it in #wctopdropnav li a, #wctopdropnav li a:link
- a padding you've defined in #wctopdropnav li

To **properly fix this issue**, rethink about the way you'll style the menu, so that your text links have some padding, but the image doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the problem is because of `#wctopdropnav li` has this:

```
padding:10px 6.5px 6.5px 6.5px
```

padding adds width and height to the original element width and height, that didn't cause a problem in text links because it doesn't have that much, but with the image it became a problem

remove padding `li` items, and give `#wctopdropnav li a`

```
line-height:35px;
```

problem fixed!

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you. I understand what you're implying. The image has a lot more padding that's transparent which is why the image appears to be out of line with the rest of the tab text. I should alter the padding around the image itself and then code it back into the html.

Comment: exactly, the image height was `30px`, by setting a value close to that to `line-height` for other elements, you first fixed the problem -*after removed top and bottom padding from the `li`*- and second you now have bigger height for your main nav links to click on, rather than 13px before it is now 35px;